# (Apache) Error log beautifier

Tags: apache, logging

Anyone knows of a good error log beautifier? (should be able to handle apache error logs).

Should be open source / free, preferably with a web interface

Comment: ah oops, missed that key word there... :)

Answer (score 3):

I use http://www.librelogiciel.com/software/ScanErrLog/action_Presentation It runs through the error log producing a summary webpage, or some other formats.  While it's best run from a regular cron-job (and it will keep a record of what it's parsed before to save effort), it can also be run as a CGI (though the demo appears to be broken).

Comment: I don't want statistics, I want the actual error log - but in formatted display, broken into columns etc

Answer (score 2):

You can see a sample report generated using [Analog](http://www.analog.cx/) and [Report Magic](http://www.reportmagic.org/) at this address: http://www.reportmagic.org/sample/index.html. The Failure Report is simple, but is a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Webalizer](http://www.webalizer.org/) to process my website's logs. Its web-interface might be a bit dated but it's very powerful, reliable and can handle very large logs. It's also quite easy to set up which a big plus in my book as you don't want to be worrying about the software, you just want to visualise the data.

Comment: I said error logs... I'm not interested in statistics

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html)

Comment: Not to mention being ancient (2006)